# Android Studio copy external native build libraries from multiple ABIs to jniLibs

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, cmake

I am building external native build library with multiple ABIs armeabi-v7a and x86 with Android Studio. The problem is that when I build the project the libraries are in these folders:

```
App/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/armeabi-v7a/libs/armeabi-v7a/libApp.so
App/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/x86/libs/x86/libApp.so
```

Where they should be in inside these locations in order to be found correctly on the device:

```
App/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/libApp.so
App/src/main/jniLibs/x86/libApp.so
```

Is there a way that they can be generated or build directly into jniLibs? At the moment I have done symlinks by hand but I hope there is automated way of handling different ABIs and different configurations.
This is my current gradle script:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.org.app"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 19
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86'
            stl = "c++_static"
        }
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                arguments "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release"
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path '../../../CMakeLists.txt'
        }
    }
    sourceSets.main {
        jni.srcDirs = []
        jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/jniLibs'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
sourceSets.main {
     jni.srcDirs = []
     jniLibs.srcDirs 'src/main/jniLibs'
}
```